# onepage checkout stuck on billing and not moving to next step

Tags: php, magento, jquery, magento-1.7, checkout

Struggling from this issue since 3 days.

When i am tested the application in windows (WAMP), everything working fine. But when i am deployed the same in Linux, Billing continue button is not working.

When i clicked on “Continue” after entering details, i am seeing in firebug

http://www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/ 200 OK

And its staying in the same page ...

Then when i checked in apache error_log, i am seeting below error:

[error] File does not exist: /home/docs/public_html/checkout, referer: http://www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/

I dont know why its going to /home/docs/public_html/checkout ???

Am i in right way of debug? Could you please help me to resolve this issue .... 
Thanks & Regards 
ecomse

Answer (score 5):

When clicking "continue" in the billing address step, the page sends an ajax post request to the`Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveBillingAction`. This function is supposed to save the form data into a quote and return a JSON object containing a property "goto_section", i.e. "goto_section":"shipping_method". The success function of the ajax request picks this property up and shows the next step.

I suggest you use the firebug debugger to check if `POST /checkout/onepage/saveBilling` returns a valid JSON object with a `goto_section` element. If not - there must be something wrong with the saveBilling function. Use Xdebug and set a breakpoint to the beginning of that function to check if everything is processed properly.

Another possible problem source is a third party extension rewriting the checkout routing configuration. Are there any possible suspects in your shop? Try to deactivate them and test if that solves the problem.

An example of a valid JSON string returned by the `saveBilling` action:

```
{"goto_section":"shipping_method","update_section":{"name":"shipping-method","html":"    <dl class=\"sp-methods\">\r\n                <dt>Flat Rate<\/dt>\r\n        <dd>\r\n            <ul>\r\n                                            <li>\r\n                                                                   <span class=\"no-display\"><input name=\"shipping_method\" type=\"radio\" value=\"flatrate_flatrate\" id=\"s_method_flatrate_flatrate\" checked=\"checked\" \/><\/span>\r\n                                                <label for=\"s_method_flatrate_flatrate\">Fixed                                                                        <span class=\"price\">$5.00<\/span>                                                <\/label>\r\n                                   <\/li>\r\n                        <\/ul>\r\n        <\/dd>\r\n        <\/dl>\r\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\r\n\/\/<![CDATA[\r\n            var shippingCodePrice = {'flatrate_flatrate':5};\r\n    \r\n    $$('input[type=\"radio\"][name=\"shipping_method\"]').each(function(el){\r\n        Event.observe(el, 'click', function(){\r\n            if (el.checked == true) {\r\n                var getShippingCode = el.getValue();\r\n                                    var newPrice = shippingCodePrice[getShippingCode];\r\n                    if (!lastPrice) {\r\n                        lastPrice = newPrice;\r\n                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += newPrice;\r\n                    }\r\n                    if (newPrice != lastPrice) {\r\n                        quoteBaseGrandTotal += (newPrice-lastPrice);\r\n                        lastPrice = newPrice;\r\n                    }\r\n                                checkQuoteBaseGrandTotal = quoteBaseGrandTotal;\r\n                return false;\r\n            }\r\n       });\r\n    });\r\n\/\/]]>\r\n<\/script>\r\n"},"allow_sections":["shipping"],"duplicateBillingInfo":"true"}
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg for your quick help. /checkout/onepage/saveBilling did not returned anything. For that, call did not even reached "saveBillingAction()".  So i am suspecting [error] File does not exist: /home/docs/public_html/checkout, referer: http://www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/  ...

Comment: Then it must be an incorrect router rewrite. Are there any extensions in your installation that deal with the checkout? Try searching for any xml files in your local and community code pools that contain the string <checkout>.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, will check it. Meanwhile its working perfectly in my windows 7 setup (WAMP) and not working with same assets in Linux, do you think that any extensions will cause these type of issues.

Comment: yes, it can be an issue - Linux systems are case sensitive while Windows are not. So it is possible there is a file in your shop's code base whose name contains incorrectly cased letters, which would not be noticed in Windows and cause this problem in Linux

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I found <checkout> in below places otherthan my customized block:   /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/config.xml, /app/code/core/Mage/Compiler/etc/compilation.xml   and /app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc/config.xml

Comment: Hi Oleg, do you have any idea about this error i am getting: [error] File does not exist: /home/docs/public_html/checkout, referer: http://www.domain.com/checkout/onepage/     i am seeing the above error in apache error_log.

Comment: Looks like some strange behavior of the Apache's mod_rewrite, possibly misconfigured. Is domain.com your base url? or is it www.domain.com? Does your vhost configuration include both www.domain.com and domain.com as server name and server alias? From what you have found looking for <checkout> I can say, it is not a routing configuration error. These are valid core modules.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, base url: http://www.domain.com/   And here are my vhost: DocumentRoot "/home/docs/public_html"
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com

Comment: Thank you Oleg, base url in core_config_date is : "http://www.domain.com/"   And here are my vhost: DocumentRoot "/home/docs/public_html"    
        ServerName domain.com     
        ServerAlias www.domain.com

Comment: Hi Oleg, below vhost file is picking up: /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf   but when i say  whereis apache, it gave
apache: /usr/local/apache      so do u think this may be the issue ...

Comment: No, that seems to be ok, vhosts settings are stored separately from the application. But I still think there must be something wrong with request rewriting configuration. At this point I am out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thank @Oleg Ishenko, I was facing the same issue and culprit was extension. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I was working locally. 
There are other shipping methods enabled which were causing this issue.
I have disabled DHL, USPS, FedEx and UPS.
Now working fine for me.

I hope this helps.